# NIOS II Assembly Outputting to DE0-Nano JP2 Pins

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, nios

what I am trying to accomplish is taking a 8-switch value from the JP1 pins and outputting a Hex value to two separate 7-seg displays hooked up to the JP2 Pins. I haven't got as far as writing the code for the certain LED segments, but was trying to get the LEDs to just light first. Below is where I've tried setting the JP2 pins to output first and storing the switch value to it but none of the LEDs light at all. I know that the pins corresponde to a 32-bit value since there is 32 pins but shouldn't the switch value passed to the JP2 pins at least light one of the LEDs?

```
.equ JP1_PORTS, 0x10000060
.equ JP2_PORTS_DIR, 0x10000074
.equ JP2_PORTS, 0x10000070
.equ O, 0xFFFFFFFF

.text
.global _start
_start: movia r2, JP1_PORTS
    movia r3, JP2_PORTS_DIR
    movia r4, O
    stwio r4, 0(r3)

    movia r3, JP2_PORTS


loop: ldwio r5, 0(r2)
      stwio r5, 0(r3)
      br loop
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a debugger (or simulator with built-in debugger) for that platform?  That's often helpful very helpful.

Comment: Have you read the datasheet for the GPIO controller?  Do you have to enable the GPIO port(s) with a clock or otherwise?  Do you have to enable the individual pins of the GPIO port(s)?    Have you measured the voltage at the GPIO outputs to see whether they're changing?  Have you read the datasheet for the display you're trying to control?